# C++11 ambiguous overload when calling variadic function template

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Could you please explain why I'm having `error: call of overloaded ‘func(const Test&)’ is ambiguous` despite the fact that I use explicit template instantiation?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
};

void func(const Test &) {
  std::cout << "By Reference" << std::endl;
}

void func(const Test) {
  std::cout << "By Value" << std::endl;
}

template <typename... TArgs>
void wrap(TArgs... args) {
  func(args...);
}

int main() {
  Test t;
  wrap<const Test &>(t);
  return 0;
};
```

**EDIT**

The reason of ambiguity is a combination of two factors. The first is that simple overload rules applied in the call `func(args...)`. The second is that simple functions cannot be overloaded by value and const reference. To ensure, one may replace the call `wrap<const Test &>(t)` with `func(static_cast<const Test &>(t))`. The error will still be there.

To solve the problem, one may use function template for `func` and value vs const reference template specialization as showed in the example provided by @lubgr

Thanks everybody to help me to demystify the concept.

Comment: even if it is not template, your call is ambiguous.

Comment: what part you do not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `wrap` function template explicitly instantiated, imagine the compiler being in the `wrap` instantiation, knowing that `Targs...` really is `const Test&`. Which function overload should then be chosen? It can't prefer one, because the template parameter of `wrap` doesn't propagate to an ordinary (non-template) function. Instead, simple overload rules apply.

You can see the difference and fix the issue if you change `func` to be a function template, too:

```
template <class T> void func(T);

template <> void func<const Test&>(const Test&) {
  std::cout << "By Reference" << std::endl;
}

template <> void func<const Test>(const Test) {
  std::cout << "By Value" << std::endl;
}
```

The appropriate specialization is called when you explicitly ask for it, then.

```
template <typename... TArgs>
void wrap(TArgs... args) {
  func<TArgs...>(args...); // Note, the type is specified here, again.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For the same reason the following calls are ambiguous:

```
#include <iostream>
void foo(int) { std::cout << "val" << std::endl; }
void foo(const int&) { std::cout << "ref" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
  int i = 1;
  foo(i);
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802142/c-function-overloading-resolution-involving-pass-by-value-reference-and-const) for full discussion of that case.